# Como eu printo dados por dados em sql?(seleciona todos os dados, porem só printa um por um em formato de array)!

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

````
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY id_pergunta";
    $execsql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Erro");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execsql)){
        # code...
        $IdPergunta = $row['id_pergunta'];
        $p = $row['pergunta'];
        $ra = $row['respostaa'];
        $rb = $row['respostab'];
        $rc = $row['respostac'];
        $rd = $row['respostad'];
        $vp = $row['valor_pergunta'];


    }
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
    echo '<root>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="IdPergunta">' . $IdPergunta . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="ValorPergunta">' . $vp . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="Pergunta">' . $p . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaA">' . $ra . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaB">' . $rb . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaC">' . $rc . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaD">' . $rd . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '</root>';


?>```
````

Comment: Somente irá aparecer o último dado passado pelo `while` no seu caso. Pra que você obtenha todos os dados, você terá que colocar todo este bloco de `echo` dentro do seu while, caso contrário, não irá printar todos os dados.

Comment: Continua na 1° pergunta

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, mas vc ta querendo dizer repetir os `echo` ?

Comment: Tenho que votar para fechar pois não dá para entender a pergunta. Você tem ser mais claro, se tem dificuldades em formular questões comente no código aquilo que fazer.

Comment: @Joãovictor, se está aparecendo apenas um dado quando tu coloca o echo dentro do `while`, provavelmente é porque está retornando apenas um dado mesmo, caso contrário, ele fará um looping e irá imprimir todos os resultados...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça isso:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY id_pergunta";
    $execsql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Erro");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execsql)){
        # code...
        $IdPergunta = $row['id_pergunta'];
        $p = $row['pergunta'];
        $ra = $row['respostaa'];
        $rb = $row['respostab'];
        $rc = $row['respostac'];
        $rd = $row['respostad'];
        $vp = $row['valor_pergunta'];

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
    echo '<root>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="IdPergunta">' . $IdPergunta . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="ValorPergunta">' . $vp . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="Pergunta">' . $p . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaA">' . $ra . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaB">' . $rb . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaC">' . $rc . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '<Pergunta id="RespostaD">' . $rd . '</Pergunta>';
    echo '</root>';

    }      

?>
```